# Mac OSX .zshrc $PATH variable ignorning local command

Tags: terminal, zsh, tidy, htmltidy

I'm on MacOSX Mountain Lion 10.8.2, using OhMyZsh and for some odd reason, I am not able to run a command which should trigger a script in my local directory. If I navigate via terminal to the folder containing "tidy" (http://w3c.github.com/tidy-html5/) I get an error when trying to run it:

`➜      tidy test.html test.min.html
zsh: command not found: tidy`

My $PATH variable looks very weird in .zshrc (I'm new to zsh, I've always used bash):

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/Keith/.rvm/bin`

Does anyone know what I could do to modify my path to check the local working directory first?

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current working directory is `.` which doesn't appear to be in your `$PATH`. You can `export` it the same way you would in `bash`:

```
export PATH=.:$PATH
```

which will add `.` before the rest of `$PATH`. You'll need to either `source ~/.zshrc` or re-open your terminal window to apply the changes. You can check whether `.` is in the `$PATH`:

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, use `./tidy` (since adding `.` to `$PATH` is considered a security risk by some).

Comment: In my situation, I actually had some permissions issues and a bad build of the tidy library, but your answer would be the most valid in the event someone was trying to figure out how to get their commands to run in the current working directory. I have two admin accounts on my computer and permissions were messed up, so I had to run Disk Utility -> Repair Permissions